# Why is the constant returned faster?

Tags: haskell

I have the following snippet:

```
import Network.MessagePackRpc.Server

ping :: String -> IO String
ping s = return s

main :: IO ()
main = do
  serve 8081 [ ("add", fun add), ("ping", fun ping) ]
```

Now, what I observe is that when I send a string with e.g. 100000 identical 1024-Byte strings to it, the small snippet runs in approximately 2s. If I go and replace return s with e.g. `return "the-1024-byte-string"` then this runs approximately 25% faster. I have exercised this up and down. I am really surprised that the impact is so huge. Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: I guess that laziness is doing something here. Did you try `ping !s = return return "the-1024-byte-string"`?

Comment: Are you compiling with `-O2`?  It is now a rule that you aren't allowed to ask performance questions on SO without first testing compiled with `-O2` and `-fllvm`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Gevalt! I don't have llvm. (Fortunately I don't currently have performance questions either.)

Comment: Have you tried with "strict" return? `return $!`. You can have a look at this [list of hints](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance).

Comment: Have tried it "all" except the llvm. the O2 makes it run faster as a whole but eventually the 20 - 30% discrepancy between both implementation stays.

Answer (score 3):

Returning a known (at compile time) constant could enable more inlining. One would have to check the generated code to be sure, however.